# How do I identify which PC made a suspicious DNS query?

Tags: windows, dns, ids, logging, incident-response

Our IDS detected a suspicious DNS packet going to a Botnet (or similar).

Since that DC is a recursive relay, how can we identify the client who made that request.  (Windows DNS server)

Comment: What are your logging capabilities? Do you have netflow?

Comment: Log files?  I believe you can turn on logging of DNS requests in windows DNS server.  I've had a colleague turn it on when I was trying to troubleshoot DNS requests, and from my recollection it recorded who made the request and what the request was for.

Comment: The IDS itself should be able to tell the origin address of that packet. Are you able to look there? If not, what's the matter? Also, you should be able to find it in the windows server event logs, you just have to use the right tool to swim in that sea of information.

Comment: I'm surprised the IDS didn't record the *source* of the DNS packet ....

Comment: Logging the source address of the DNS-Request at the gateway isn't usefull because in recurisve queries the DNS-Server is the one who is aking the "outside" DNS-Servers for answers. So the source address will always be the one of the DNS-Server

Comment: Also, you likely have to turn the logging of requests on in the windows DNS server.  At least our server had it off by default.  So in this case you'd need to wait until the suspicious request happened again.

Comment: These things tend to be quite active. If you turn your DNS logging, it probably won't be long until the little brat tries to phone home and shows up again.

Answer (score 1):

DNS request logging on your local DNS forwarder (Domain Controllers) is the easiest.  Blocking TCP/UDP port 53 outbound except for your Domain Controllers lets you be assured that only they can do recursive DNS lookups.

Netflow is another option, but has large data storage requirements since you are storing lifecycle and endpoint information about all UDP and TCP sessions in your network.

For effective NSM (Network Security Monitoring) you should have both DNS logging and Netflow enabled and it's worth getting both in place well ahead as logging that isn't a matter of standars practice will be disregarded as hearsay in court proceedings.  You can't just turn these on, gather stuff, use it as evidence, and turn them off again.